# Fix Jumpy PulltorefreshView List in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am working on chat application in android. I'm using [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) code for Pull to Refresh functionality in my application.My problem is when i click on Editext for writing the message , soft keybaord appears and if pulltoRefresh List have 1 or 2 elements , the list scrolls up to the top but if pulltoRefresh List have enough items to cover the whole screen then the list works properly(it doesn't scrolls up to the top.)

Following is my Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
                                       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                       android:id="@+id/parent"
                                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                       android:background="@color/white"
                                       android:orientation="vertical">


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonsFrame" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="6dp" android:background="@drawable/routecover_bg">

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/messages_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center" android:padding="2dp">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/ic_headermessageselect" android:id="@+id/msg_icon"/>  
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/locations_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center"  android:padding="2dp">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/ic_headerlocation" android:id="@+id/location_icon"/>  
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/members_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center"  android:padding="2dp">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/ic_headermember" android:id="@+id/member_icon"/>  
       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


            <ChatWindow                           android:id="@+id/messages_window"
                                                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                                  android:layout_weight="1"
                                                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Code for the Chat Window:

```
  public class ChatWindow extends FrameLayout{

private PullToRefreshListView listView;

public ChatWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public ChatWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public ChatWindow(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

@Override
public void init(Context context){
    setupview(context);
    initialiseList(context);
}

@Override
public void setupview(Context context) {

    LayoutInflater mInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View contentView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.chat_window, null);

    listView = (PullToRefreshListView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.chatlist);
    listView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener() {
       @Override
       public void onRefresh(){
        }
     });

    this.addView(contentView);

}

    }
```

Code of chat_window layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="0dip"  
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">    

 <PullToRefreshListView
           android:id="@+id/chatlist"  
           android:dividerHeight="2dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:smoothScrollbar="true"
           android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
           android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
           android:stackFromBottom="true"
           android:scrollbars="none" 
           android:divider="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/parentcontainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/bg_menubar">


    <EditText   android:id="@+id/name" android:hint="Compose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="6dp" 
                android:paddingBottom="6dp" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                android:paddingRight="10dp" 
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                />

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/send_button"
                 android:background="@drawable/bg_sendbutton"
                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for my reference, you mean to say you want the addition to you list item from the bottom of the screen instead of top correct?

Comment: I would recommend Chris Banes Pull to Refresh, its had alot of opts done and is very smooth now - https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh